# display message on stopping data export to excel in vba

Tags: vba, export-to-excel

I have a button to export data to excel file from mysql database. 
The data export works fine. But when i break the export procedure(press and hold Esc button), it produces an error(Run time error '3059' Operation cancelled by user). How can I display a message that the process has been break by user. Is there any event or something to do that?. I just need to make some codes run when the execution is interrupted.

Comment: What error message? You mean the message isn't "Code execution has been interrupted"?

Comment: Yup the execution is interrupted. So I need to do something when that happens., like show a message or something@dwirony

Comment: Well if the actual message is *code execution has been interrupted*, then the code isn't running anymore, so adding new code isn't going to help anything.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Tht's not the actual message. *Run time error '3059' Operation cancelled by user*. This is the actual message

Comment: Don't you think that could possibly be somewhat relevant to the question? Please [edit] your post to **show your handler code** and include the actual error message.

Comment: sure...When that happens some of my codes are not executing. I have the codes, I just don't know where to put it. I need to make it run when the error occur.

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use on error goto in the sub

```
private sub button_click()
  On Error GoTo catch
  //codes to execute when esc button is not pressed
sub:
  MsgBox "Data Export Cancelled"
  Exit sub
End Sub
```